# Nextjs revalidatePath Function in App Router for Nested Routes

Tags: next.js

Salutations! We are working on a project where we need to dynamically revalidate multiple pages within a specific segment of our Next.js application. Specifically, we have a nested route structure like this: *mainPath/[id]/subPath/[subPathId]*. I want to revalidate all **[subPathId]** pages for a given **id** without having to revalidate each one individually.

Next Version: 14.0.1
React Version: 18.2.0

```
app/
└── mainPath/
    └── [id]/
        ├── page.js
        └── subPath/
            └── [subPathId]/
                └── page.js
```

Objective: Dynamically revalidate all [subPathId] pages under a specific id segment.
Current Approach: Utilizing revalidatePath, but unclear on how to target all [subPathId] paths for a given id without individual revalidation calls.